# Jenkins - Post Build to a Folder

Tags: jenkins, post-build-event

does jenkins have a post build process such that the build WAR files can be made to be stored particular folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to move built files.  The first is through plugins.  Which plugin you use depends on where you want to store things.  Try looking at these sections of the Jenkins Plugin list:

- [Artifact Uploaders](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Artifactuploaders)
- [Other Post-build Actions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Otherpostbuildactions)  (Some of them are "hidden" in here.)

The second way of moving built files is to brute force the move by creating a Jenkins build step to execute a set of shell commands.